# Valid source of Greek historical periods , in a URL

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, historiography, resource, greece

I am writing a paper and I have to include all the historical eras of Greece as a pre-defined "vocabulary" for a metadata schema. This vocabulary has to be online and be accessible via a URL.

So I am searching for a URL that contains all the historical eras of Greece in a format like "era name" - "date started" - "date ended".

I cannot find a valid source. I want the source to be official. I used lots of keywords, Googling but nothing worthy except wikipedia. Can you suggest anything more official and trustworthy?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Asking for reference material" is [explicitly off topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://people.umass.edu/dfleming/english704-timeline.html

The above page maintained by [University of Massachusetts Amherst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Massachusetts_Amherst) professor David Fleming should meet your requirements, although he is an English lecturer and that timeline is evidently only for his Classical Rhetoric class.

You'll find no "official" source for this per se - the dates usually given are determined mainly by convention. To be really academically rigorous, you should probably be linking an book or individual articles to attest to the dates of each period.

Which is pretty overkill for dates of periods, though. Something like the [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greece#History), or the [timeline on Ancient History Encyclopedia](https://www.ancient.eu/ajax/ajax_print_visual_timeline.php?tag=greece&width=950&height=600), or even just a information site like [this](http://ancient-greece.org/history/overview.html) should suffice.